# Bulk store a dictionary in redis without iteration

Tags: python, mongodb, redis

I have a large dictionary and I would like to store it in redis. I can do this by iterating through it but this will take a long time.

```
for k,v in my_dict.iteritems():
    r.hset('my_dict', k, v)
```

Is there a way to bulk store it (similar to how I can do it in Mongodb, simply by uploading the dictionary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the iteration is mandatory. That said, you could improve on the above with either or both of the following "tricks":

- Use pipelining - this is pretty well documented, but the gist is creating a pipeline object with `r.pipeline()`, batching some commands and then calling the object's `execute()` method.
- Use variadic commands - you can call `r.hmset()` with (iterated) chunks of your dictionary.